# Как скачать файл из мета-поля и подсчитать количество загрузок?

Tags: wordpress

У меня есть этот мета-поле, содержащий Идентификатор прикрепленного файла

например

```
get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'test_file', true)
```

Мне нужно скачать этот файл , а также подсчитать количество загрузок в мето-поле, используя этот код.

```
$postID = get_the_ID;
$number_downlode = get_post_meta($postID, 'downlode_registration', true);
$number_downlode++;
update_post_meta($postID, 'downlode_registration', $number_downlode);
```

Но я не знаю, как это сделать.

Я пробовал использовать команду onclick вместе с ajax

```
<?php setPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?>    
<?php $GET11 = wp_get_attachment_url ( get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'test_file', true) );?>  
<a href="<?php echo $GET11 ?>" download onclick="isEmail()">Click Me</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
function isEmail() {
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'script.php',
                success: function(data) {
                 document.write("data");
                }
            });

}); }
</script>
```

script.php

```
$postID = get_the_ID;
$number_downlode = get_post_meta($postID, 'downlode_registration', true);
$number_downlode++;
update_post_meta($postID, 'downlode_registration', $number_downlode);
```

Но файл script.php не видит wordpress

Я также попытался скачать файл, используя метод POST

```
<?php 
  if ( get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'test_file', true) ) : 
  $GET11 =   get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'test_file', true) ;
?>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="downlode" name="test_downlode">
</form>
<?php if ($_POST['test_downlode']){ 
$number_downlode = get_post_meta($postID, 'downlode_registration', true);
$number_downlode++;  
update_post_meta($postID, 'downlode_registration', $number_downlode);
$file = ($GET11);
 if (file_exists($file)) {
    if (ob_get_level()) {
      ob_end_clean();}
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;}}
  endif; ?>
```

Но сколько я не пробовал, страница не видит файл в переменной $file

Мне нужно, чтобы вычисление выполнялось через метаполе, так как потом я буду фильтровать страници через get_posts().

Плагины тут не подойдут.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения этой задачи надо сделать две вещи: перехватить клик на ссылку и отдать файл реальный пользователю средствами php.

Что происходит при клике на фиктивную ссылку, указывающую на несуществующую страницу сайта? WordPress инициализирует ядро и пытается выдать страницу 404. В этот момент надо вмешаться своей функцией, обновить счётчик загрузок и отдать реальный файл. Ниже код такой функции.

```
/**
 * Rewrite download link by its url.
 * Increase download count.
 */
public function rewrite_download_link() {
    /** @var wpdb $wpdb */
    global $wpdb;

    $uri  = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $path = wp_parse_url( $uri, PHP_URL_PATH );

    if ( 0 === strpos( trailingslashit( $path ), self::$link_base ) ) {
        $download_link = untrailingslashit( $path );
        $url           = self::get_url( $download_link );
        if ( $url ) {
            $count = self::get_count( $url );
            $data  = array(
                'count' => ++ $count,
            );
            $where = array(
                'url' => $url,
            );
            $wpdb->update( self::$table, $data, $where );

            self::download_file( $url );
        }
    }
}
```

Функция `rewrite_download_link()` срабатывает на событии `init`, и проверяет, не начинается ли url с `$link_base`, например, это может быть `/downloads/`. Любая ссылка вида `http://site.org/downloads/cool.jpg` считается фиктивной и подлежит обработке, в которой обновляется счётчик загрузок, вычисляется реальный url файла и вызывается функция отдачи реального файла пользователю.

Код этой функции приведён ниже.

```
/**
 * Download file.
 *
 * @param string $url file url.
 */
private static function download_file( $url ) {
    if ( ! $url ) {
        return;
    }

    $file_path = ABSPATH . wp_make_link_relative( $url );

    $file_name = pathinfo( $file_path, PATHINFO_FILENAME );

    $file_extension = pathinfo( $file_path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );

    switch ( $file_extension ) {
        case 'png':
            $content_type = 'image/png';
            break;
        case 'gif':
            $content_type = 'image/gif';
            break;
        case 'tiff':
            $content_type = 'image/tiff';
            break;
        case 'jpeg':
        case 'jpg':
            $content_type = 'image/jpg';
            break;
        default:
            $content_type = 'application/force-download';
    }

    header( 'Expires: 0' );
    header( 'Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate' );
    header( 'Cache-Control: pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0', false );
    header( 'Pragma: no-cache' );
    header( "Content-type: {$content_type}" );
    header( "Content-Disposition:attachment; filename={$file_name}.{$file_extension}" );
    header( 'Content-Type: application/force-download' );

    // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine
    readfile( "{$file_path}" );
    exit();
}
```

Функция `download_file()` делает полученную ссылку на файл относительной и вычисляет путь к файлу, а потом отдаёт его средствами php. Таким образом, пользователь не имеет возможности узнать, где находится реальный файл и скачать его напрямую.

Полный код класса, который содержит приведённые выше методы, можно [найти на нашем GitHub](https://gist.github.com/kagg-design/241fdef594c326a33423ff74f6bd6115).